# Bridged VMware cannot detect any physical network adapter

Tags: networking, vmware-workstation, bridged

I have installed VMware Workstation 10.0. My PC has 3 network adapters (Bluetooth, Ethernet and Wireless). And i have already installed drivers for it.

[image: adapters].

But these adapters haven't detected in VMware.

[image: cannot detect adapter]

I have tried my best to search solution on Internet for this problem but found nothing. So anyone can help me, please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recently struggled with VMware bridging on a Win81 host. My solution was to sidestep VMware's bridging altogether, which seems to be broken on Win8 due to conflicts with the MS Hyper-V virtual switch. Instead, I created a host-only network segment for the VM and then used the host network to bridge the virtual adapter to the physical host adapter. This works much better.

1. In the Virtual Network Editor for the VM, create a new Host-only network segment. **Do not enable DHCP.** The name doesn't matter, but in this case I am using "VMnet2".
2. In your host Windows machine, create a bridge between VMnet2 and the actual (physical) adapter. In this case, my actual adapter is "Wi-Fi". The newly created adapter may appear as "Ethernet" -- refresh the list of network adapters to see the actual names. Select "Wi-Fi" and extend (Ctrl-click) to include "WMware Network Adapter VMnet2", then right-click and select "Bridge Connections". This may take up to 30 seconds or so to complete, after which there will be a new "Network Bridge" item.
3. In the Workstation window, create the VM network adapter: Open the guest VM in Workstation, click Menu > VM > Settings, click "Add..." and create a new Network Adapter using VMnet2.
4. In the guest VM, verify the adapter address. Boot up the VM and use ipconfig to verify that the IPv4 address of the adapter is on the WiFi subnet.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the VMWare Bridge Protocol Service is installed on the hosts network adapter (right click network adapter and select properties).

If not (In the network adapters properties window):

1. Click Install
2. Select **Service**
3. Select **VMWare** for **Manufacturer**
4. Select **VMWare Bridge Protocol**
5. Click **Ok**
6. Click **Ok** to close the properties dialog
7. **Restart** the **host**
8. Reconfigure the VM adapter for Bridging

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a personal fix I noticed, but in the case of bridging, I achieved it by [opening the configuration option in the VM settings.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDExn.png)

There are quite a few virtual and physical adapters, all of which are set on by default. I selected only the physical adapter in my computer and deselected the rest. Bridging worked fine after that.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the VMWare Bridge Protocol Service is started

In elevated command prompt:

net start vmnetbridge